# Firewall blocks connection to second WebSocket server

Tags: websocket, webrtc

In short we have two separate servers for our web app. The first one is the main server that uses Websockets for handling "chat rooms", and the second server only handles WebRTC audio chat rooms via Websocket. Both servers use Express to create a HTTPS server, use secure Websocket and the port 443.

I recently encountered a problem where a corporate client's firewall blocked the wss-connection to only the WebRTC server. The error logged in the user's browser was "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT", which means the user never connects via Websocket. This has not happened with any other clients.

The Websocket connection works normally between the user and the main server, and no rules have been added to their firewall to use our app.

Has anyone encountered something similar? What kind of a firewall setting might cause this? Could this be a cors problem, since the servers are on their own sub-domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the main server WebSocket used TCP and the WebRTC server used UDP, and UDP was blocked by corporate firewall on default.

WebRTC should use TCP as a backup, but I'm assuming UDP is still needed for the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

The main server could be restricting the type of data sent on port 443, which will use SSL to secure that transmitted data.

Refer to this [page for information on the "Well-know port numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

The WebRTC audio data may need to be transmitted on its own dedicated port number that has been configured on the main server for this.